# JavaScript: create function that accepts callback as input and returns function; Output depends on invoke count

Tags: javascript, callback

The objective of my code is:

Write a function "once" that accepts a callback as input and returns a function. When the returned function is called the first time, it should call the callback and return that output. If it is called any additional times, instead of calling the callback again it will simply return the output value from the first time it was called.

I tried the code below:

```
const once = (inputFunc) => {

  let invCount = 0; 
  let firstCallOutput; 

  return function (num) {
    invCount ++; 

    if (invCount === 1){

      firstCallOuput = inputFunc(num); 
      return inputFunc(num); 
    }

    else {
      return firstCallOuput; 
    }
  }
}

const addByTwoOnce = once(function(num) {
  return num + 2;
});


// UNCOMMENT THESE TO TEST YOUR WORK!
console.log(addByTwoOnce(5));  //should log 7
console.log(addByTwoOnce(10));  //should log 7
console.log(addByTwoOnce(9001));  //should log 7
```

My code console logs out the correct values (7) in all three situations.  But it fails 2/3 test specs.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How can I pass the two test specs?

Comment: Typo: `firstCallOuput`

Comment: oh my gosh!  you are right ... thank you; dumb mistake on my end

Comment: The lines "*`firstCallOuput = inputFunc(num); 
      return inputFunc(num);`*" do call the callback twice already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified `once` function -

```js
const once = (f, memo) => x =>
  memo === undefined
    ? (memo = f(x), memo)
    : memo

const addTwo = x =>
  x + 2

const addTwoOnce =
  once(addTwo)

console.log(addTwoOnce(5))  //should log 7
console.log(addTwoOnce(10))  //should log 7
console.log(addTwoOnce(9001))  //should log 7
```

If you want to safeguard the call site from being able to set the memo, you can make the memo a local variable instead of a parameter -

```
const once = f =>
{ let memo
  return x =>
    memo === undefined
      ? (memo = f(x), memo)
      : memo
}
```

Or maybe you want to safeguard against the potential for the user-supplied function to return `undefined`. These are all choices you can make with minimal impact on the semantic structure of the code -

```
const once = f =>
{ let hasRun = false
  let memo
  return x =>
    hasRun
      ? memo
      : (hasRun = true, memo = f(x), memo)
}
```

---

Related: `constant` will return a *constant* value, regardless of its input -

```js
const constant = x => _ =>
  x

const always7 =
  constant(7)

console.log(always7(5))  //should log 7
console.log(always7(10))  //should log 7
console.log(always7(9001))  //should log 7
```

---

Related: `memoise` will cache a value for *each unique input*, only recomputing `f` if the input has not been seen before -

```js
const memoise = (f, memo = new Map) => x =>
  memo.has(x)
    ? memo.get(x)
    : (memo.set(x, f(x)), memo.get(x))
    
let fib = n => 
  n < 2
    ? n
    : fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
  
console.time("original")
console.log(fib(40))
console.timeEnd("original")
// 1503.43 ms

fib = memoise(fib)

console.time("memoised")
console.log(fib(40))
console.timeEnd("memoised")
// 0.175 ms
```

Comment: well, it could be simply `? memo = f(x)`. But generally, this is too over-simplified - what if the source function does return `undefined`? A cleaner implementation would still need a counter, like the OP does.

Comment: This isn't simplified, just minified. There's no good reason to declare the `memo` variable as a parameter.

Comment: @georg if the function returns `undefined`, expect *undefined* behavior... I don't know why people try to work against `undefined` instead of putting it to work for them.

Comment: @user633183: I don't know, `once(() => console.log('hello'))` looks like a realistic use case to me.

Comment: @georg no it doesn't. Describe a program that makes repeated calls to some function `f` that ignores all inputs, produces no outputs, and oddly logs some constant value but *only* on the first application. That's a bad program. Compare to `const effect = f => x => (f(x), x); const log = effect(console.log); const logOnce = once(log); logOnce("hello");` which works as intended, puts inputs and outputs to work, and washes your contrived example away.

Comment: well, how about, in your own example, `logOnce(window.someOptionalStuff)`? Would it log only once?

Comment: @georg, `undefined` input warrants *undefined* behavior... stop over-thinking it. It's a code smell to write null-checks in every function and it's senseless to expect everything to work when values are suddenly missing. If it throws an error, misbehaves, or breaks, it *should*, because you have a problem in your code to fix. Functional style introduces many techniques to mitigate the problem, all of which are out of scope of this answer.

Comment: Anyway, nitpicking in comments like this is almost always a fruitless endeavour. I provided an update which shows how the programmer can make all of these choices on their own. I appreciate the discussion, thank you.

Comment: @user633183: no problem. In the future, please try to restrain from personal remarks.

Comment: @georg huh, what?

Comment: @Bergi: that's not exactly minification, but rather an appetite for single-expression function bodies.  While they can have similar results, the motivation is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok**,
First we will create a `once` function that accepts a callback function.
**Then** we need to create a variable to check if this is the first time or not.
You can make a boolean variable or counter whatever you want. OK,
**Then** we make a variable `result` to grap the output of the callback with the initial value of *0*

```
function once(func) {
    let isOnce = true
    let result = 0
}
```

OK, after that, let's create a function that will return the callback value if this is the first time, and if not, we will just return the output value from the first time, which we stored to the `result`

```
function once(func) {
  let isOnce = true
  let result = 0
  function runOnce(num) {
    if(isOnce) {
     isOnce = false
     result = func(num)
     return result 
    } else { 
      return result
    } 
  }
}
```

**Finally**, we will return the `runOnce` function.

```
function once(func) {
  let isOnce = true
  let result = 0
  function runOnce(num) {
    if(isOnce) {
      isOnce = false
      result = func(num)
      return result 
    } else { 
      return result
    }
  }
 return runOnce 
}
```

Ok, now we need to create a callback function that takes the input and increments it by 2.

```
function addByTwo(input) { 
  return input + 2
}
```

So, time to check

```
const always7 = once(addByTwo);
console.log(always7(5))
console.log(always7(10))
console.log(always7(9001))
```

It always runs once and gets the same result every time.
[the result is always be 7, click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgYNc.png)